# AWS Amplify not Redirecting URL

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am new to AWS and deployed my default react app on `AWS Amplify`, I am using GoDaddy for my custom domain, and added that domain to my `amplify application` from `domain management` with status `available`.

Lets say that domain is `xyzexample.info`, I have added forwarding for this Domain in GoDaddy which translates it to `https://www.xyzexample.info`.
But when i try to access it with url `https://xyzexample.info` it does not resolve to `https://www.xyzexample.info` although I already have a rule in `Rewrites and redirects` as `302 (Redirect - Temporary)`.
these are the things that I have tried so far, what could be the problem?
If I am missing any details please let me know. this is what i have in my rewrite and redirect.
[image]